# Javascript Prototype Oriented Programming doubts

Tags: javascript

I want to do the following in Javascript

```
function A(){
    this.B = function() { ... };
    this.C  = function() { <<I need to call B() here>> } ; 
};
```

I have read the following way of method overloading, but I want to know whether professional programmers would do it this way. I.e. if you would only do this as an exercise or experiment or would actually do this in production code.

```
function foo(a, b, opts) {
};
foo(1, 2, {"method":"add"});
foo(3, 4, {"test":"equals", "bar":"tree"});
```

Comment: What does the first part have to do with your question?

Comment: Homework assignment? Your original question contained "1." and "2." and some bad copy-paste errors. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Agree with Kenneth. Please reword yor question.

Comment: I don' see the connection. There is no prototype? Clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Just call B() from inside C();

```
function A(){
    B = function() {
         // Do something here
    }
    C = function() { B(); }
};
```

Or, if you just want to create an alias

```
function A(){
    B = function() {
         // Do something here
    }
    C = B
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The clean way would be :

```
var A = function() { };

A.prototype.B = function() { };
A.prototype.C = function() { this.B(); };
```

The prototype is just a static set of properties that is cloned inside every new instance you create.

The difference between what you're doing and this is that in your case, methods are created and added when you are in the "constructor" of the object, while with this method they already are properties of the object before you enter its "constructor", and are only parsed once (when you add them to the prototype) instead of being parsed everytime you create a new instance, which is faster.

I think, correct me if i'm wrong.

```
var A = function() {
    // this scope is what i mean by "constructor".
};
```